# Bind value to a XAML mscorlib double

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, data-binding

I have some double (could also be bool, int, etc) i want to get as resources.

This can be easily done with xaml types. For instance:

```
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"                    
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Demo.MyClass"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyColorResource" Color="{Binding Source={x:Static local:MyClass.Current}, Path=MyColor}"/>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Where "MyColor" is a hex color in a string (#ffffff).

However, I don't know if it is possible to do the same with this types, as I cannot find where to bind the value:

```
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"                    
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Demo.MyClass"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

    <sys:Boolean x:Key="MyBoolResource"/>
    <sys:Int32 x:Key="MyIntResource"/>
    <sys:Double x:Key="MyDoubleResource"/>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

The point is doubles being used as resources later:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <!-- This works -->
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MyColor}/>
    <!-- Not sure how to deal with this -->
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="{StaticResource MyDouble}/>
</Style>
```

So the question is, is there a way to bind the value of a double? Something like this:

```
<sys:Double x:Key="MyDoubleResource" Value={Binding MyDouble}"/>
```

Currently im binding the Height property, for instance, to the double propertie in code. But the code i have to wirite for that is longer than a static resource and it is being repeated all over the code.

This

```
<Setter Property="Background"  Value="{StaticResource MyColor}"/>
```

is sorter than:
This

```
<Setter Property="Background"  Value="{Binding Source={x:Static local:MyClass.Current}, Path=MyColor}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your resources like this:

```
<sys:Double x:Key="MyDoubleResource">20</system:Double>
<sys:Boolean x:Key="MyBoolResource">false</system:Boolean>
```

And use them like this:

```
<Button Height="{StaticResource MyDoubleResource}" IsEnabled="{StaticResource MyBoolResource}">Test</Button>
```

Comment: I have edit the question. My question is how to set a double value as a resource. So i can do {StaticResource MyDoubleResource}

Comment: I don't really understand what the question is. The way you defined the resources, it should work.

Comment: How i set a value for <sys:Boolean x:Key="MyBoolResource"/>?, this resource has no value yet. How is its value binded?. Thanks for the quick response btw